# Name parts of iterables in itertools.products

Tags: python, python-itertools

I've been reading about `itertools`, which seems to be a very powerful module. I am particularly interested in `itertools.product()` which appears to give me all of the combinations of the iterable inputs.

However, I would like to know which of the input iterables each of the outputs are coming from. For example, a simple standard example is:

```
itertools.product([1, 2, 3], [1, 2])
```

If the user provided the inputs of [1,2,3], [1, 2] I won't know which order they came in, so getting a result of

```
(1, 2)
```

isn't much help, as I don't know which way round they will be. Is there some way of providing input like:

```
itertools.product(foo = [1, 2, 3], bar = [1, 2])
```

and then getting outputs like:

```
output['foo'] = 1
output['bar'] = 2
```

or

```
output.foo = 1
output.bar = 2
```

Comment: From the documentation I'd say it always comes in the order of the parameters.

Comment: Felix, that is exactly correct.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The output of `itertools.product([1, 2, 3], [1, 2])` is a series of ordered pairs whether the first element comes from `[1,2,3]` and the second element from `[1,2]`.  This is guaranteed behavior.

If field names are desired, you can cast the result to a [named tuple](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).  As you requested, the named tuple lets you access the fields with `output.foo` and `output.bar`.  Incorporating KennyTM's idea of using `**items`, it can be packaged in a single function that is fast and memory efficient:

```
from itertools import product, starmap
from collections import namedtuple

def named_product(**items):
    Product = namedtuple('Product', items.keys())
    return starmap(Product, product(*items.values()))
```

Here's an example call:

```
>>> for output in named_product(foo=[1,2,3], bar=[1,2]):
        print output

Product(foo=1, bar=1)
Product(foo=1, bar=2)
Product(foo=2, bar=1)
Product(foo=2, bar=2)
Product(foo=3, bar=1)
Product(foo=3, bar=2)
```

Answer (score 5):

The result will always be ordered according to the argument order of product, i.e. in `(1, 2)` the `1` must come from `[1,2,3]` and the `2` must come from `[1,2]`.

Therefore, your requirement can be satisfied by reusing itertools.product:

```
def named_product(**items):
    names = items.keys()
    vals = items.values()
    for res in itertools.product(*vals):
        yield dict(zip(names, res))
```

Comment: It would be better to return a namedtuple than a dictionary.  The latter is more expensive to create, takes more memory, and loses the order of the cartesian product.  That being said, +1 for the creative use of ``**items``.