# How to print the name of the variables with python itertools combinations

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

Suppose I have the following code where allModelsPredComb is a list of 3 elements, where each elements is a tuple of size 2 , where each tuple is an array.

```
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np

list1 = np.random.randint(125, size=100)
list2 = np.random.randint(125, size=100)
list3 = np.random.randint(125, size=100)


allModelsPred = list([list1, list2, list3])
allModelsPredComb = list(combinations(allModelsPred, 2))

for c in range(len(allModelsPredComb)):
    sum = np.sum(allModelsPred[c][0]) * np.sum( allModelsPredComb[c][1])
    print(sum)
```

So the result gives the sum of all combination thats to say 3 in total. It prints something like. (Please dont care about the values of numbers that s not the problem)

```
807768
778360
70180
```

The problem is that it is not clear for the user to what correspond each combination. Hence, I would like to add the name of the lists.

So I would like my results to look like;

```
list1, list2
807768
list1, list3
778360
list2, list3
70180
```

How can I achieve this?

PS : I'm not a Python expert. Therefore, my question may be of a more generalist character. In other words, not only related to itertools.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Name parts of iterables in itertools.products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098194/name-parts-of-iterables-in-itertools-products)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question does have similarities to the one mentioned by Georgy in the comment, although it is definitely different. Taking your question more specifically, how about something like this:

```
from itertools import product, combinations
import numpy as np

def named_product(**items):
    values = list(items.values())[0]
    names = list(combinations([value[0] for value in values], 2))
    combs = list(combinations([value[1] for value in values], 2))
    return list(product(zip(names, combs)))

list1 = tuple(("list1", np.random.randint(125, size=100)))
list2 = tuple(("list2", np.random.randint(125, size=100)))
list3 = tuple(("list3", np.random.randint(125, size=100)))
list_of_lists = [list1, list2, list3]

for output in named_product(lists=list_of_lists):
    print("Using", output[0][0])
    # change this if you want a different function with the arrays
    print(np.sum(output[0][1][0]) * np.sum(output[0][1][1]))
```

Sample output:

```
Using ('list1', 'list2')
38061730
Using ('list1', 'list3')
40047770
Using ('list2', 'list3')
41575604
```

Let me know if that doesn't answer your question.